# regex is not working properly - preg_replace or preg_match

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have the following regex code:

```
$search_query=preg_replace('#[a-z. .a-z]#i', ' ', $_POST['searchquery']);
```

My database is lower case. The interpretation that I am going for is:  `$search_query` should allow all letters on a case insensitive basis and any white space but ignore symbols and numbers.  It should not replace anything since it is case sensitive.  And it should process 'search_query'.

Where am I going wrong...?  My hashtags are correct and is i=case insensitive...

Examples of INPUTS are: user enters "populate". Another user enters "bLaH". A third user enters "BIG".

Comment: Show us some input examples with desired outputs after preg_replace, explaining, what your are trying to achieve.

Comment: Try adding a `^` to your regex as the first character in your character class. [Example](http://regexr.com?365ov)

Comment: `[a-z. .a-z]` is a very strange regex... `[a-z. ]` would do the same. It's almost the opposite of what you mean, I think.

Answer (score 0):

`'#[^a-z ]#i'` seems to work very well.